# How to extract data from object?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
[56, SensIOP, 9, Open Point] - Index 0
[562, SensIOP, 92, Open Point2] - Index 1
```

This is my object I am getting from the database call.I am iterating over the list to get this ,now my question here is 1st and 3rd field are long and others are string , how can I extract this from the object , to assign it to some variable.

Update :

```
 Object object = (Object) iterator.next();
```

This object has the value set one (Index 0 )(It's in for loop)

Update 2 :

```
  for (Iterator iterator = List2.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Object object = (Object) iterator.next();
```

Comment: please provide the code that you are getting these values

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're fetching data, but when I get data in the format specified by you, I do the following:

```
List<Object[]> objects = query.list();
if (objects.size() > 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < objects.size(); j++) {
        Object[] object = objects.get(j);
        BigInteger firstValue = (BigInteger) object[0];
        String secondValue = (String) object[1];
        BigInteger thirdValue = (BigInteger) object[2];
        String forthValue = (String) object[3];

        long firstValueLong = firstValue.longValue();
        long thirdValueLong = thirdValue.longValue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the result with the help of 'RAS' post its works greate thanks

```
List<Object> resultList =(List<Object>) em.createNativeQuery("SELECT isbillpayable,isothracctrfable FROM usrfacaccounts ").getResultList();

          for (Iterator<Object> it = resultList.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Object[] object = (Object[]) it.next();
            String firstValue = (String) object[0];
            System.out.println("isbillpayable"+firstValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cust it into a long for long property to assign.

for example

```
Long l = (Long) yourOblList.iterator().next();
```

see why generic comes [generic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
using this function you can get result :

 String a1= arrayname[0] ; //[56, SensIOP, 9, Open Point] 

 a1=split(',',a1);
 String Fisrtval=a1[0];
 String Thirdtval=a1[2];
```

Please refer : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/util/StringHelper.html#split(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: It is object like Object object = (Object) iterator.next();